# How to delete row by double-clicking?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, double-click

I'm new to java, so my knowledge is quite limited. I already want to excuse now, if I have overlooked some rather obvious solution.

I'm having a problem trying to make a function in my program, so that the user can delete a row (from a `JTable`) by double-clicking on it. I've tried to use this code:

```
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
     if (e.getClickCount() == 2) {
        JTable target = (JTable)e.getSource();
        int deletedRow = target.getSelectedRow();
            myTableModel.removeRow(deletedRow);

            myTableModel.fireTableDataChanged();
        } 
     }
```

`myTableModel` extends from `AbstractTableModel`. I hope some of you are able to help me.

Comment: What happens? Do you get an exception?

Comment: I don't get any reaction at all.

Maybe I should add that my table is called jTable1 and that it's the model that's called myTableModel.

jTable1.setModel(myTableModel);

Comment: Have you executed it in a debugger? Are you sure that you are entering the block and that deletedRow is returning a valid row?

Comment: Netbeans debugger finds no problem

Answer (score 2):

> myTableModel extends from AbstractTableModel.

I don't know what that means. I assume it means you are using the DefaultTableModel, because that implements the removeRow(...) method.

There is no need to invoke the fireTableDateChanged() method. The removeRow() method of the DefaultTableModel will do that for you. It is the responsibility of the TableModel to invoke these methods, not your custom code.

Is you method being executed? By default a double click with invoke the editor of the cell you double clicked on. So you need to override the isCellEditable(...) method of your table to return false. Then a double click will be invoked on the table and your listener code should be invoked.

Also in your event code you access the table, so you should get the model from the table to make sure you are accessing the proper model:

```
DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)table.getModel();
```

If you need more help (and in the future when you post a question) then post your [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)  because we can't guess what you are doing based on a couple of lines of code.

Comment: Yes sorry. It is the DefaultTableModel. I was a bit confused.

Nice to know that I don't have to invoke the fireTableDateChanged.

My method is not being executed, at least Netbeans shows no sign of activity when I double click on a row.

I don't really know what you by overriding isCellEditable. So far I have: 'code'public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        return false;
    }

Should I just put an @Override before it?

Comment: If your event code is not being executed, you need to post your SSCCE. I can't guess what your code looks like.

Answer (score 1):

```
 int c = evt.getClickCount();
    if (c == 2) {
        int res = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Are you sure to delete this data?", "", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
        switch (res) {
            case JOptionPane.YES_OPTION:
            int p = table.getSelectedRow();
            DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();
            model.removeRow(p);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Delete Successfully");
            break;
            case JOptionPane.NO_OPTION:
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Delete Action is Canceled");
            break;
        }

    }
```